# Progress bar not redirecting to another page and not disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

There is a variation of threads on this topic but unfortunately none appears to address my issue.

Our progress bar is design to display when page loads and this progress bar is doing just that.

The issue is that after showing progress bar briefly, user is supposed to be redirected to another page called classes.aspx.

This is not happening. The progress bar does not disappear and does not redirect to another page.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Below is the exact code I am using.

//HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Main" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Class Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, IE=8, IE=9, IE=10, IE11,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowProgress() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var modal = $('<div />');
                modal.addClass("modal");
                $('body').append(modal);
                var loading = $(".loading");
                loading.show();
                var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            }, 200);
        }
        $(window).load(function () {
            ShowProgress();
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/images/favicon.ico" />
    <style type="text/css">
            .modal {
           position:relative;
           top:-1em;
           z-index:100;
        }
        .loading{
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            margin-top:400px;
            margin-left: 0px;
            background-color: White;
            z-index: 999;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="loading" style="margin-top:100px;margin: auto;">
        Loading. Please wait.<br />
        <br />
        <img src="images/loader.gif" alt="" />
    </div>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

//VB

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Partial Public Class Main
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Response.Redirect("classes.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the backend, you are not letting the Page_Load. You are just redirecting the page. The front end code executes only after the Page_Load

Comment: @Zee, thank you for your prompt response.

If this is what you mean, ```If Not IsPostBack Then
Response.Redirect("classes.aspx")
End If`, I have tried that but nothing changed.

I have also tried adding Handles like:
```Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load`

When I add the Handles Me.Load, the user gets redirected but then the progress bar does not display. It just redirects user to the classes page.

Comment: Can you remove the Response.Redirect("Classes.aspx"); line and check if the progress bar shows?

Comment: @Zee, yes, it still shows.

Comment: so you want to show a progress bar when it loads, and after a little delay redirect to another page?

Comment: @Zee, that's correct